# Suggest a good keyboardless tablet pc, that supports Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tablet, ubuntu-netbook-remix, touchscreen

I need a keyboard-less tablet pc that has these specs (Ordered by the most wanted to the least):

- Supports Ubuntu OR Ubuntu remix (just works very well, no need to official support).
- Touch screen (Keyboard-less)
- Has camera OR usb ports
- Screen size from 5" to 14" (Like if there was something out of this range!)
- Slim
- Cheap (Yes, I can afford something around 500$, But If it's one choice I would pay 1000$)!
- Tough (yes I don't want it to break easily)

** Multi touch is never an issue!, I have no plans to use this feature

I want to use it as a demo device in to put my Computer Science (IT) Graduation Project in.

I know that there is a numerous tablets that work on Windows 7 or the iPad but I really want one that works with Ubuntu because I'm a developer and need open-solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notion Ink Adam.. but you have a wait someday for it to be available. Will cost around $400 in india..
With nVIDIA Tegra CPU, Screen 10", Camera 3MP, 16 hours of battery, supports Android, Ubuntu and Chromium.. What not!

[Check it all out here..](http://www.technoholik.com/news/exclusive-a-sneak-peek-at-the-notion-ink-adam-tablet-specs-pics/)

Comment: Unbelievable!, I hope they deliver it to Jordan.

Answer (score 1):

The SmartQ5 and SmartQ7 are both Ubuntu based tablets, and they are currently available.  They are quite cheap and have most of the features you are looking for.
Here is a link to a [video review of the SmartQ5 on YouTube.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nMMzcHhvbM)  Hopefully, it meets your needs.  I haven't personally used one, so I can't vouch for their durability.